How to Run a Specific Spec File During `globalSetup` in Playwright?
I'm trying to run a specific spec file (math.spec.js) during the globalSetup phase in Playwright. The goal is to execute this spec file before any other tests run.
Here's the structure of my project:
/my-project
|-- tests/
|   |-- e2e/
|       |-- pos/
|           |-- math.spec.js
|-- playwright.config.js
|-- global-setup.js

In global-setup.js, I want to run the math.spec.js file using the Playwright test runner. I've tried using Node's child_process to execute the command, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach or if there is a built-in way in Playwright to handle this.
global-setup.js:
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

module.exports = async () => {
  try {
    // Attempt to run the specific spec file
    execSync('npx playwright test tests/e2e/pos/math.spec.js', { stdio: 'inherit' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error running math.spec.js in global setup:', error);
    process.exit(1); // Exit with a failure code if the test fails
  }
};

playwright.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  globalSetup: require.resolve('./global-setup.js'),
  // Other configurations...
});

Questions:

Is this the correct way to run a specific spec file during globalSetup in Playwright?
Are there any best practices or potential issues with this approach?
Is there a more Playwright-native way to achieve this?

I'm using Playwright version 1.46.1 and Node.js version 20.15.1.

Just curious: why do you want to run this file before another spec? Specs should generally not be dependent on state being set by other specs. One exception is logging into the app.

We need to do some preparations in the UI before running our entire test suite. I know this is not good practice & we should ideally use endpoint to prepare the stage, but management wants this regardless...

If you need the test spec to run before every suite executes, you can make it its own project and your other projects can list it as a dependency.
export default defineConfig({
  testDir: './tests',
  // ...
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'math',
      testMatch: /math.spec.js/,
    },
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
      dependencies: ['math'],
      // only include the following if you don't want math to run as part of the project as well
      testIgnore: /math.spec.js/
    }
  ]
});


It works partially. Now when I run npx playwright test --ui, I only the match.spec.js file, but not the rest of the spec files

@ManuelAbascal because you need to select chromium project in ui
